# Swift: ScrollView not scrolling (how to set the constraints)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints, setcontentview

I am trying to set up a scroll view with auto layout in my storyboard and populate it with a couple of buttons in code, but the scroll view doesn't scroll and I don't understand how to set up the constraints to make scrolling available?

Especially how to set the constraints to the content view (what's that?).

In storyboard the scroll view is placed at the bottom of the screen (20 pix to the safe area) and from leading to trailing. It has a size of 375x80.

Now in code this is how the scroll view is populated with buttons and how it is set up:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var xCoord: CGFloat = 5
    var yCoord: CGFloat = 5
    let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 70
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 70
    let gapBetweenButtons: CGFloat = 5

    var itemCount = 0

    for i in 0..<CIFilterNames.count {
        itemCount = 1

        // Button properties
        let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        filterButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
        filterButton.tag = itemCount
        filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.filterButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        filterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        filterButton.clipsToBounds = true

        //Code for filters will be added here

        let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        let coreImage = CIImage(image: originalImage.image!)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(CIFilterNames[i])")
        filter!.setDefaults()
        filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let filteredImageDate = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageDate, from: filteredImageDate.extent)
        let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!)

        // Asign filtered image to the button
        filterButton.setBackgroundImage(imageForButton, for: .normal)

        // Add buttons in the scrollView
        xCoord += buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons
        filterScrollView.addSubview(filterButton)

    }

    filterScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: buttonWidth * CGFloat(itemCount + 2), height: yCoord)
    filterScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true


}
```

Depending on the device size 4 or 5 buttons are shown, but not more and scrolling is not possible.

What can be done to make scrolling possible?

Answer (score 0):

Reason is in itemCount , you're settings it to itemCount + 2 will be 3 as itemCount is 1 from the for loop so , set it to equal array size

```
   filterScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: buttonWidth * CIFilterNames.count  , height: yCoord)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will be much better off using auto-layout over calculating sizes - gives much more flexibility for future changes.

Here is an example you can run in a Playground page. I used the "count" as the button labels, since I don't have your images. If you add images, you can un-comment the appropriate lines and remove the `.setTitle` and .`backgroundColor` lines:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import CoreImage

class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    var CIFilterNames = [
        "CIPhotoEffectChrome",
        "CIPhotoEffectFade",
        "CIPhotoEffectInstant",
        "CIPhotoEffectNoir",
        "CIPhotoEffectProcess",
        "CIPhotoEffectTonal",
        "CIPhotoEffectTransfer",
        "CISepiaTone"
    ]

    let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 70
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 70
    let gapBetweenButtons: CGFloat = 5

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a UIScrollView
        let filterScrollView = UIScrollView()

        // we will set the auto-layout constraints
        filterScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // set background color so we can see the scrollView when the images are scrolled
        filterScrollView.backgroundColor = .orange

        // add the scrollView to the view
        view.addSubview(filterScrollView)

        // pin scrollView 20-pts from bottom/leading/trailing
        filterScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        filterScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
        filterScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true

        // scrollView height is 80
        filterScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true

        // create a UIStackView
        let stackView = UIStackView()

        stackView.spacing = gapBetweenButtons

        // we will set the auto-layout constraints
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // add the stackView to the scrollView
        filterScrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        // with auto-layout, scroll views use the content's constraints to
        // determine the contentSize,
        // so pin the stackView to top/bottom/leading/trailing of the scrollView
        // with padding to match the gapBetweenButtons
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: gapBetweenButtons).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterScrollView.topAnchor, constant: gapBetweenButtons).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -gapBetweenButtons).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -gapBetweenButtons).isActive = true

        // loop through the images
        for i in 0..<CIFilterNames.count {

            // create a new UIButton
            let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
            filterButton.tag = i

            // we will set the auto-layout constraints, and allow the stackView
            // to handle the placement
            filterButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            // set the width and height constraints
            filterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth).isActive = true
            filterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonHeight).isActive = true

            filterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            filterButton.clipsToBounds = true

            filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            // this example doesn't have your images, so
            // set button title and background color
            filterButton.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
            filterButton.backgroundColor = .blue

//          //Code for filters will be added here
//          
//          let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
//          let coreImage = CIImage(image: originalImage.image!)
//          let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(CIFilterNames[i])")
//          filter!.setDefaults()
//          filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
//          let filteredImageDate = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
//          let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageDate, from: filteredImageDate.extent)
//          let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!)
//          
//          // Asign filtered image to the button
//          filterButton.setBackgroundImage(imageForButton, for: .normal)


            // add the image view to the stackView
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(filterButton)

        }

    }

    func filterButtonTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        if let b = sender as? UIButton {
            print("Tapped:", b.tag)
        }
    }

}

let vc = TestViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```